# T-SQL: Months in Top 5 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Base query is:

```
SELECT Top 5 
[Year], [Month], Title, Units, [Rank]
from aTable
WHERE [Year] = @Year and [Month] = @Month
order by [Rank] desc
```

What I would like to add, is a [Months in Top 5] column, that would show me a number of consecutive months each of the rows in Top 5 has been rank 5 or less.

Comment: By "consecutive months" do you mean to exclude non-consecutive months? If something is top 5 in January, but not in February and is top 5 again in March then the current count should not include January?

Comment: Yes, I mean how many months in a row it has been in top 5. If it was #5 for a year, dipped to #6 in April and came back to #3 in May, I want to show that it has been in Top 5 for 1 month.

Comment: And if it isn't in the top 5 currently not show in the results at all?

Comment: Correct, only the current Top 5 is of interest

Answer (score 1):

```
;with myTable as (
    select
        dateadd(yy,[Year]-1900,0) + dateadd(mm,[Month]-1,0) YearMonth,
        Title,
        Units,
        Rank
    from
        aTable
),
results as (

    select
        YearMonth,
        Title, 
        Units, 
        [Rank]
    from
        myTable
    where
        YearMonth = dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,getdate()),0) and
        Rank <= 5
    union all
    select
        b.YearMonth,
        b.Title, 
        b.Units, 
        0 Rank
    from
        myTable b
        join results a on
            b.Title = a.Title and 
            b.YearMonth = dateadd(m,-1,a.YearMonth) and 
            b.Rank <=5
)
select 
    max(YearMonth),
    Title,
    sum(Units) Units,
    max(Rank) Rank,
    count(*) MonthsInTop5
from
    results
group by
    Title
order by
    Rank Desc
```

Comment: OP wants count of consecutive months in top 5, not total count.

Comment: This is good, but like Goat said, it shows total number of months in Top 5, not the last consecutive.

Comment: The answer will use a recursive CTE.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've updated my answer with a recursive CTE that should provide what you need.

Comment: Note: The Units field in the result is the total units sold over the period that the Title was in the top 5. You can change that if you like. Replace `b.Units` with `0 Units` and replace `sum(Units) Units` with `max(Units) Units`.